# When two useState setters are being used in a click handler only one works

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, use-state

I have made a small stopwatch component using hooks in react. This is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem.

Look at the function named `resetTicks`. It has two setters `setTicks` and `setTicking` and only the `setTicking` works i.e. the clocks gets paused and interestingly if I click the button again only then it resets the clock. I tried reordering the calls to both setters to no avail.

```
const StopWatch = () => {
  const [ticks,setTicks] = useState(0);
  const [ticking,setTicking] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (ticking) setTicks(ticks + 1);
    },10);
  },[ticks,ticking]);

  const toggleTicking = e => {
    setTicking(!ticking);
  }

  const resetTicks = e => {
    // these two setters are causing the issue
    // only the setTicking is actually showing effect. I have tried switching 
    // their order but nothing works.
    setTicking(false); 
    setTicks(0);
  }

  const min = Math.floor(ticks / 6000);
  const sec = Math.floor((ticks - (min * 6000)) / 100);
  const centis = ticks % 100;
  return (
    <WatchWrapper>
      <WatchDisplay>
        <span>{min < 10 ? '0': ''}{min}</span>
        <span>:</span>
        <span>{sec < 10 ? '0': ''}{sec}</span>
        <span>:</span>
        <span>{centis < 10 ? '0' : ''}{centis}</span>
        </WatchDisplay>
        <WatchControls>
          <WatchBtn onClick={toggleTicking}>
            {ticking ? 'stop' : 'play_arrow'} 
          </WatchBtn>
          <WatchBtn onClick={resetTicks}>refresh</WatchBtn>
        </WatchControls>
      </WatchWrapper>
    )
}
```

Comment: Initially, you defined the value of ticks as 0 and after clicking also defining it `setTicks(0)`, Hence component is not re-rendered. Try by setting it with a different value other than 0;

Comment: @DurgeshPal No. I am clicking in the reset button when the clock is running so the ticks is already changed due to many many `setTicks` calls with different values.

Comment: Yes. But I think that somehow it is setting 0 value in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tricky one, you should get idea what's going on from `console.log`:

```
true
56
true
57
true
58
true
59
false
0
false
60
```

It does get set to 0 but apparently at some point the old `setTimeout` which was scheduled fires, which had a **closure** on old value of tick when it was 60, so it resets it back to it.

Increase the timeout to say 3 seconds do a  `console.log(ticking, ticks)`
in render and it should be more obvious to you what the problem is.

Comment: Oh my. You have such a keen eye. Why didn't I even think of this. Funny thing is I had it in my head when writing the effect that "Man there is gonna be a scenario where this timeout fires pre-scheduled and i am gonna run into a problem" but It didnt occur to me when the actual problem hit.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the race-condition between `setTicks` setter and asynchronous call of callback inside `setTimeout`. The `setTicks` setter updates the ticks count but the old ticks count has been stored inside the `setTimeout` scope. So the `setTimeout` raises the callback giving it the old value of `ticks` as parameter. You need to clean up the `setTimeout` on component unmount in order to prevent that:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      if (ticking) setTicks(ticks + 1);
    }, 10);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [ticking, ticks]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that there is no race condition you could try to reset the setTimeout before resetTicks by creating a React Reference for the timer.

```js
const [ticks,setTicks] = React.useState(0);
const [ticking,setTicking] = React.useState(false);
const timer = React.createRef();
React.useEffect(() => {
    timer.current = setTimeout(() => {
        if (ticking) setTicks(ticks + 1);
    },10);
},[ticks,ticking, timer]);

const toggleTicking = e => {
    setTicking(!ticking);
}

const resetTicks = e => {
    clearTimeout(timer.current);
    setTicking(false); 
    setTicks(0);
}
```

Test with Codesandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/test-reset-race-condition-g53l5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&view=editor

Answer (score -2):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (ticking) setTicks(prevState => prevState + 1);
    }, 10);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [ticking]);
```